# Webdriver Remote cannot install Firefox Extension

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I have the following code to connect to a remote webdriver instance and install an extension for Tampermonkey.

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'en,en-US')
options.add_argument('--log-level=3')  # Not logs will be displayed.
options.add_argument('--mute-audio')  # Audio is muted.
options.add_argument('--enable-webgl-draft-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')  # Disable popup
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')  # and info bars.

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension('/path/to/tampermonkey.xpi')

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4445/wd/hub", options=options, browser_profile=profile)
```

However when I go into the driver, it does not look like tampermonkey was actually installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firefox Webdriver Install Addon to Remote Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72891019/firefox-webdriver-install-addon-to-remote-webdriver)

Comment: I just answered your same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74839465/3917161. I also marked this question as a duplicate of that question.